# Shadows in unity are pixelated in android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

The shadows get pixelated after I build and run on my android device. I am using unity 2017. This pixelated shadows doesn't appear in unity's game view or scene view. The type of lighting is directional.

At the start it looks like this
[image]

The object along with the camera is moving in the x axis (direction is going away from screen). After some time it will look like this.
[image]

I tried every advice I found in the forums including tinkering with shadow settings in the QualitySettings, making the shadow resolution high, then low. Changing shadow distance from 1 to 10. I made the light follow the camera. Tried hard and soft shadows. Adjusted near plane, bias, etc. At this point I'm just trying each and every combination of adjustments. Nothing has worked yet. Can this be fixed or Am I just solving this the wrong way?

Comment: This definately has to do with quality settings, the shadows in the lower quality tier are aweful

Comment: It was the distance that was doing the pixelated shadows.
I tried to relocate the object and camera to (0,0,0) after running 500 units. It became clear when it was relocated to (0,0,0) then gradually got worse again as it moves farther again. (note: at 500 units the shadows are already very bad).

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/making-an-open-world-map-could-use-some-input.484643/#post-3164102